# Is atheism a property of an individual?

Tags: ontology, atheism

So this is an argument I'm actually having, silly as it may seem. Can atheism be said to be a *property* of an individual? His argument is that it the *lack* of a property is not a property at all. This seems to make little sense to me. The notorious odorlessness and colorlessness of carbon monoxide certainly seem like properties of sorts and from what I've seen on SEP "atheism" certainly seems to meet many of the criteria mentioned, such as that it can be predicated on individuals. What is your stance on this issue?

Comment: Perhaps this might clear things up:

http://www.rationalskepticism.org/nontheism/are-dogs-atheist-t50451-420.html#p2299817

Comment: You may wish to see http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/if-p-is-a-property-then-is-not-p-a-property . Also, do you mean *being atheist* is a property? Because athe-*ism* is a property is weird for other reasons.

Comment: Hello. "from what I've seen on SEP "atheism" certainly seems to meet many of the criteria mentioned״ - Which SEP article? Which criteria?